# Why is BootstrapValidator not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I am new to web development , and here I know that the problem is very minor but even after two days I a m not able to find it. Could you people look at this code and point out my mistake please

my code id [here @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw0afL1u/)
thanks

**HTML**

```
<form id="registerForm" action="\register" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.registerForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    }
                }
            },
            pass1: {
                validators: {
                    identical: {
                        field: 'pass2',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            pass2: {
                validators: {
                    identical: {
                        field: 'pass1',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem ? exactly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/uw0afL1u/1/ if you change the class to id from works

Answer (score 3):

To get a node by the id use: `$('#registerForm')`. If you get by `$('.registerForm')` the JS will looking for the class `registerForm` in the `<form>` tag.

Read the jQuery API's is a good way to prevent errors like this.
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is bound to the class registerForm, not the id. Change .registerForm to #registerForm in your JavaScript code.

Edit: 
Or add class="registerForm" to YouTube form element in html

Answer (score 0):

In Html form is assigned with an `id="registerForm"` and in js file you are calling a function with respect to class `$('.contactForm')` just change `$('.contactForm')` to `$('#contactForm')` hope that will solve your problem.